# Generating XML with SSIS - What are best practices

Tags: json, xml, ssis

So I'm trying to generate an XML from data that I receive in a JSON file. 
What I've done so far is that I had stored each field in the JSON as a keypair. So a row would be FieldName, FieldValue, and JSON_PK.
I have a second table that I created in order to create the XML. It has the JSON FieldName, equivalent XML FieldName, and indentation. The plan was to create a loop in SSIS to manually create the XML.
It was suggested to be that I use instead the FOR XML in my query.
However I've run an issue that every field is named FieldName. It's complicated by fields that hold their values like this `<Form submittedDate="2020-01-01"/>`
So before I go back to creating a loop to create my XML, I'm wondering what are best practices? I can't be the first one to run into this issue.
Thanks! 
A quick followup because it was requested:
This is the approximate for that the JSON comes in as, except is far longer:
{
"name": "Mylist",
"id": "9e8-19c9-e5",
"templateName": "VDashboard - Plus",
"categories": [
""
],
"attributes": [
{
"name": "Division ID",
"value": "ABCD",
"Id": "123",
"units": null,
"timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
"errors": null
},
{
"name": "ETA ",
"value": null,
"Id": "123",
"units": null,
"timestamp": "2021-01-25T21:24:36.2514056Z",
"errors": null
},
{
"name": "ETA Destination - Estimated Time",
"value": "1/11/2021 4:15:34 PM",
"Id": "123",
"units": null,
"timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
"errors": null
}
]
}

And I need to output it as an XML File.
I need to import it into the DB because I do transformation of certain fields.
Output should look at bit like this:

2020-12-03T08:00:00-05:00
  0011

My table structure looks like this. It's done so that I won't have a different table for every report:
Name VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
ID VARCHAR(50),
TemplateName VARCHAR(50),
AttributeName VARCHAR(50),
AttributeSubName VARCHAR(50),
AttributeValue VARCHAR(50),
AttributeID VARCHAR(50),
AttributeUnits VARCHAR(50),
AttributeTimestamp DateTime,
AttributeErrors VARCHAR(50),

Comment: If you have the mapping table you could maybe join to that to get the XML names to then use in your FOR XML, but we need data examples in both formats (JSON now and desired XML output) along with your table structures and even some code your using and what you have tried so far

Comment: I think if you provided some sample input and output it would help, me at least, better understand what you're trying to deliver.

Comment: Also, is it a requirement that you land the json data into the database or is this exercise really just transforming json into XML?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the issue.
Initially, I had hoped to put the JSON into a table, and create the XML by putting those values into a string with xml tags around it.
This XML though requires both Elements and Attributes and it's contents are dynamic. Therefore creating an SQL query was far too difficult to create and harder to troubleshoot.
I found that the easiest way was to create the whole thing in C#.
I used a script task to use C#. Also, I needed a table that functions like an XREF or Data dictionary. I could join it on the contents of the JSON in order to specify what the XML should look like.
Using the object XMLWriter, I created the XML, and based on the format that the XML should take, I used the functions WriteStartElement, WriteElementString, WriteAttributeString, WriteEndElement, and WriteEndDocument I wrote the XML.